# Download pdf from url that returns an embedded plugin

Tags: vb.net, pdf, web-scraping

I am looking to download a pdf from a url using vb.net code. The url returns a page with an embeded pdf plugin. I want code that would automatically download and save the pdf. Here is a sample url
http://www.sigmaaldrich.com/MSDS/MSDS/DisplayMSDSPage.do?country=PK&language=en&productNumber=S9888&brand=SIAL

Comment: Your question appears to asking people to write code for you; that's not what StackOverfloew is for.  Please visit http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and then edit your question appropriately.  You'll get better results.

Answer (score 0):

1. Download the HTML source of the source URL using [WebClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez801hhe(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2) like this

   `Dim myWebClient As New WebClient()`
   `myWebClient.DownloadFile("http://example.com/somepage.html", "downloadedpage.html")`
2. Then run [regular expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs600312(v=vs.110).aspx) against this `downloadedpage.html` like this: `iframe.+src\=\"(.+)\"`: it will return the first match as the source of PDF file. You may play with Regular Expressions online at [Regexp Hero](http://regexhero.net/tester/)
3. compose the final link to PDF file by adding `http://example.com` plus the sub-url you have extracted on step `2`
4. finally, download the final pdf file from the link you've composed on step `3`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have followed your suggestion till step 3 and obtained the sub-url but when I try to download it using WebClient.DownloadFile(url, filename) I get a "We are sorry, file not found" page instead of the file. Loading the sub-url in the browser also produces the same page.

Comment: @sami seems like the source server checks for the referral url or the header that should originate from the same server